# Search filesystem in an electron app

Tags: node.js, filesystems, electron

Is it possible to search/index a filesystem/hard-disk (windows or mac or linx) using an electron app. Is there a node package/functionality which can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are modules on npm to search the file system. See:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/find
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-finder
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-find-files
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-grep
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-matcher

Before searching the file system you can try searching npm.

Comment: nodejs standard 'fs' is powerful, too! +1for "Before searching the file system you can try searching npm." :)